# Share project in Android Studio that has already been shared

Tags: android-studio, svn

I somehow imported an Android project to my Subversion SVN using an option "Import into Subversion" and "Checkout from Version Control". I realized that my import is not how I wanted. Probably I should have used "Share Project (Subversion)" in the first place, but now there's of course no "share" option anymore.

Is there any repository metadata that needs to be deleted on order to make "share" option available again?

Tried it with Settings -> Version Control and removed directory  but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any repository metadata that needs to be deleted on order to
>   make "share" option available again?

Yes, there is. SVN places hidden `.svn` directory at the root of working copy. I guess that you should remove it and reopen the project to make 'Share' command available again. You could also checkout a new working copy of the imported/shared project.

Frankly speaking, those 'Import' and 'Share' commands in the IDE are kind of confusing. When you 'Import' a project, you simply add it to the remote SVN repository and commit this change. Importing does not make your local project a SVN working copy and does not enable any version-control capabilities. You should checkout a working copy of the project after importing it. On the other hand, when you 'Share' a project, you import it to remote Subversion repository **and** you also make your local copy to be SVN working copy enabling version-control capabilities.
Android Studio is based on [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/meet-intellij-idea.html). Therefore IDEA's documentation should also work for Android Studio. Read these help topics

- [Importing a Local Directory to Subversion Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/importing-a-local-directory-to-subversion-repository.html)
- [Sharing Directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-directory.html)

Comment: That worked, thanks! I agree, those commands are quite confusing, especially for a newbie like me.